# Do callbacks lengthen/refresh session? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, callback, timeout

So, I have a page that uses callbacks. When I attach VS10 debugger to IIS and set breakpoint in Page_Load() handler, app stops on breakpoint each 30 seconds, which is of course correct. Yet when session timeouts (for testing set timeout value to 5mins) every next callback results with error about: "Response.Redirect()" and callback.

Question is same as title. Also if they don't,is there any way to enlong/refresh session without refreshing page, which results in loss of data in controls. Also how would storing all controls values in cache minute before timeout and then, after refresh rewriting these values to refreshed controls, work? (control data -> cache -> refresh -> cache data -> controls).

Edit: "Response.Redirect cannot be called in a Page callback." This is error message I get.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, callbacks reset the sessionState timer back to 0.

Comment: So what can that bug be caused by? It happens only after timeout should happen.

Comment: Also do callbacks refresh cookies?

Comment: A callback would not renew the session, a partial postback would